# Where to put permissions facebook login? Request new permission error

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

i can't really describe much about my problem, It used to work correctly, but now i cant login anymore, i am stuck on this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has been closed.
```

Where should i put permissions?

This is my login code

```
private boolean isResumed = false;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback =
        new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session,
                             SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
            }
        };
SharedPreferences userpref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);

    userpref = ControlActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("UserPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    editor = userpref.edit();
    //facebook login
    Log.v("test","Main oncreate facebook");
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    loginfragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.hide(loginfragment);
    transaction.commit();
    //end facebook login

    // Create fragments.

    //Loading fragments in viewpager*******************************************************
    Log.v("test","Main oncreate");
    PrepareFragments();
    _viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    _viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
    _viewPager.setAdapter(_fragmentPagerAdapter);
    _viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

}
```

OnSessionStateChange method

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // Only make changes if the activity is visible
        if (isResumed) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            // Get the number of entries in the back stack
            int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            // Clear the back stack
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
                manager.popBackStack();
            }
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                // If the session state is open:
                // Show the authenticated fragment
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {

                                        _viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                                        _viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
                                        _viewPager.setAdapter(_fragmentPagerAdapter);
                                        _viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

                                        Log.v("test","pref"+userpref.getString("user_firstname","null"));
                                    } 
                                }
                            }
                    );
                }
                transaction.hide(loginfragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {

            //requesting permission
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));
                session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                transaction.show(loginfragment);
            }
            transaction.commit();
        }

    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you facebook app in your device? yes then just signout from facebook app
then fully uninstall your app. and then install your app and check. thats it...

Comment: Sorry for late answer but that doesn't work in my case, i even added "Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);" in onActivityResult without success.